# JS/CSS load issue in HTML from Isolated Storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have a HTML and JS file inside the application package of WP8 app and at runtime move the files to Isolated storage and then navigate the Browser to the html page.

### as give in the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333036/Include-static-JS-CSS-image-files-from-IsolatedSto) here

When I keep these files in the folder and zip that folder and at run time unzip the files and do the same as above the page is rendered on the browser but CSS and JS files etc do not load

Please help

Comment: What's your code? Without it we can only speculate as too what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved as I corrected the IO operation in Local Storage by including the size of file stream rather than buffer stream. This resulted in \u0 appendage in the JS file hence the error